# Restart PPP connection from C#

Tags: c#, networking, connection, ppp

I have to restart a PPP connection on Windows 2k and XP from a C# program.
How can I do that ? Does I have to disconnect and reconnect ? How ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [DotRas](http://dotras.codeplex.com/) library. It works well !